# What laws have amended the Equality Act 2010?

Tags: united-kingdom, england-and-wales, legal-research, research, equality-act-2010

I find myself wishing to download a copy of the Equality Act 2010 in order to study it when lacking internet access. Of course legislation.gov.Uk offers a PDF kings printer version, but I fear this is out of date.

Meanwhile I also fear that it will somewhat not be as navigable: can you click links in the contents too focused views of each section as in the HTML?

Is there any way to download an up to date and ideally navigable version of the Equality Act 2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is the list of changes made to the *Equality Act 2010* since its enactment](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/changes/affected/ukpga/2010/15). You can also view the entire Act, as amended to date [here](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2010/15). After each section, it lists the revisions since inception. Not all sections are fully in force, but this can be read in the commencement information following sections that were not fully in force from the time of Royal Assent. For example, s. 36 is only partly in force as of today.

"The revised legislation on legislation.gov.uk is the official revised version of the statute book for the UK in electronic form" (The National Archives, "[Guide to Revised Legislation on legislation.gov.uk](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/pdfs/GuideToRevisedLegislation_Oct_2013.pdf)", October 2013).